# Mushroom soy sauce, brand identification or substitution

Tags: sauce, food-identification, mushrooms, soy, soy-sauce

I am hoping someone knows what brand this.  A few years ago I found this mushroom soy sauce.  It was exceedingly thick, very darkly colored (almost stained one's fingers, it was so dark and concentrated, and dripped black on lightish foods till it diluted down to merely dark brown), enormously savory and salty enough to make a person shiver.  It is the best soy sauce I've ever tasted.

I bought it from a small asian food shop where I was at school, which has since closed down.  I remember it was called mushroom soy sauce, (possibly descriptors like dark or superior(?) in there), but I don't recall the brand, and I don't have a picture.  If it helps the bottle label was pale, yellow or gold or tan, non-english characters, with a red cap, and the bottle looked brown but was actually clear, just glazed with sauce inside.

So, I would like to know how to get either  this or some similar kind of soy sauce.  Some of the various brand's mushroom soy sauce descriptions I find online include different descriptors or reviews that mention terms like sweet, or light, or bitter or sour, which I'm not looking for or recalling in the sauce I had, and descriptions are not always consistent across reviews. Soy sauce in the grocery stores seems pretty thin and sloshy, even tamari which is reportedly on the very dark and savory end of soy sauces. I wouldn't mind liquidy if I knew the flavor would be quite strong, but I don't know how to tell.

I would really rather not buy a half-dozen different soy sauces to find what I'm looking for.  I would like to know what sauce (brand) this is, or what product(s) might be generally available^ that would be very close^^, if the original is not findable or not commonly available.

^ Preferably in regular non specialized grocery stores (USA, PA if that helps), or large, easily findable and navigable online websites with non-exorbitant shipping.

^^ thick, dark, strongly-flavored, salty, savory.  Preferably not sweet.  Would take a product that's liquidy or non-mushroom if it's also strongly flavored, salty and savory.

Comment: This doesn’t sound like soy sauce. There is a vegetarian “oyster sauce” made with mushrooms that might be a better match.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're looking for.

[image]

Comment: So you think it is Pearl River Bridge brand? can you tell me a bit about *why* you think so - ie, is it a sauce you've tasted, that matches my description, or only one you've heard about, is it the flavor or texture that makes you think it is this brand rather than another?  The bottle looks alright, but the manufacturer's description on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Pearl-River-Bridge-Mushroom-Flavored/dp/B01M6A03MU) calls it "salty-sweet", in the comparison chart.  Is there a sweetness to it, do you know?  I don't think I recall one, but maybe they don't mean as sweet as I imagine?

Answer (score 0):

> It was exceedingly thick, very darkly colored (almost stained one's fingers, it was so dark and concentrated, and dripped black on lightish foods till it diluted down to merely dark brown),

Sounds *exactly* like a dark soy sauce (or 老抽 in Chinese). It is thick and used to colour food in Chinese cuisine. But it is almost always with a slight sweetness to it due to the addition of caramel or molasses and it is mostly not as salty as light soy sauce.

Oyster sauce in comparison is much more thicker, sweeter, and not as staining.

草菇老抽 (usually called mushroom flavoured dark soy sauce) is the version with added straw mushroom extrait and usually thicker and more flavourful.

Pearl River Bridge and Lee Kum Kee are the most available brands in North America. But in my experience they both have sweetness to it. The PRB one has 4.5 g of carbohydrates per 15 mL while LKK has 4.7 g. If your soy sauce indeed had superior in its name, it is most probably PRB.

Haitian, a popular brand in China, produces one with 3.5g carbohydrates per 15 mL and not as sweet, but I do not think it is as available in North America, but you can try to find it. Another brand, Master (味事达, a Kraft Heinz subsidary in China) is even less sweet, but I have never seen it in Canada at least.

Comment: Note that although popular brands of oyster sauce like Lee Kum Kee are quite thick, smaller brands tend to have thinner sauces, more like soy sauce.